# How peristent is router state in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have an app where I set the store state as follow :

`history.replace(location.pathname, {myValue: 1});`

I know, one way to clear it is doing `history.replace(location.pathname, {});`

but I was wondering, what other way this state is replaced ?

It looks like this happen when I click on a `<Link to={"/new/url"}/>` but are there other situation ? how persistend is that state ?

Comment: What routing/navigation package and version is your app using?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use [connected-react-router](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router) if you are using Redux.
Otherwise, you have to build it by yourself.

Basically, you need to have a listener to catch the event "popstate".

> A popstate event is dispatched to the window each time the active
> history entry changes between two history entries for the same
> document
> ([Mozila MDN Web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate))

Here is a very basic example:

```
function useLocation () {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(window.location)

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('popstate', handleChange)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('popstate', handleChange)
  }, [])

  const handleChange = ()=> setLocation(window.location);

}
```